# Remove a view from TabBarController

Tags: iphone

I'm using a TabBarController to select the first view of that spec. part. From this I've to push other views which have to removed later. Example (ReviewDetailController is an UIViewController):

```
ReviewDetailController *ctr = [[ReviewDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReviewDetail" bundle:nil];
```

... do some initializing and then

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = ctr;  
[ctr release];
```

This works, but I find no way to go back to the previous view.

Because it is not a navigationController, I can't use pushViewController and later popViewController. 
But to push and to pop is what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I did understand this rightly, but maybe you can use this

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
      didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Store your topfrontViewController and you can switch between them.

Remember to set the delegate.

Comment: Thanks!  I save the topfrontViewController and restore with: <br>  - (IBAction) goBack: (id) sender {
 VocTrainAppDelegate *appDelegate = (VocTrainAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedViewController = prevController;
}